# Error message "Failed to load resources" after deleting images in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have uploaded multiple images in WordPress and I deleted some of it because I don't need them anymore. But when I inspect my elements I got Error message "

> Failed to load resources: the server responded with a status of 404

".
I have searched the image link in my WordPress media library but  cannot find it. Please see attached images.
[image]

why those deleted image link is still showing after I deleted those images? Because that errors is slowing my website.

Comment: How did you delete the images?

Comment: @disinfor: I deleted the images from back end.

Comment: Did you remove the images from the front end as well? Is your content still trying to call them?

Comment: @disinfor: what does removing images from front end mean? I deleted those images from back end and its not showing up in landing page but those removed images url is being loaded when loading website. **Are those error due to cache?**

Comment: Sorry, to be more clear - is your landing page content still trying to call those images? If you delete them from the back end, it won't automatically remove the code from the content.

Comment: @disinfor: Yes its still calling those deleted images.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199918/discussion-between-sunjeep-and-disinfor).

Comment: Vote to close this, as the reason this is happening is because the image was still being called as a background image.

Comment: ok then what will be its solution then?

Comment: It looks like you use a theme builder of some sort, so just go remove the background from those sections in your editor